# create Json array of individual user accounts from a php database query

Tags: php, mysql, json

My question is: is my json_encoded output correct below and if not how can it be fixed?

I'm trying to query a database for a list of users that all share a phone.  Once I have that list I want to store it in a json array so it can be picked up by an xcode app.  On the xcode app the user will then be able to select the user they are looking for (I'm not building the app just giving the developer a way to talk to my DB).

The user enters a phone number into the app which is posted out to a page where I catch it in my php like so:

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, name, surname, perm, branch, mob, branchaddress1, branchpost FROM users WHERE mob=%s AND (status=%s OR status=%s OR status=%s)", GetSQLValueString($_POST['phoneNumber'], "text"), GetSQLValueString('1', "int"), GetSQLValueString('3', "int"), GetSQLValueString('8', "int"));
$Result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbcon);
$userNum = mysql_num_rows($Result1);

if ($userNum > 0) {
    $array = array();
    while ($userDet = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result1)) {
        $array[] = $userDet['forename'] . ',' . $userDet['surname'] . ',' . $userDet['mob'] . ',' . $userDet['branchaddress1'] . ',' . $userDet['branchpost'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    $false = 'false';
    echo json_encode($false);
}
```

this is currently outputting

> ["john,doe,0777777777,some address,some postcode","jane,doe,0777777777,some address,some post","john,doe,0777777777,some address,some postcode","]

I think my result maybe wrong as I cant see how the developer would be able to differentiate between each of the accounts as they all seem to bleed into each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do in your loop:

```
while($userDet = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result1))
{
    $array[$userDet['id']] = $userDet['forename'].','.$userDet['surname'].','.$userDet['mob'].','.$userDet['branchaddress1'].','.$userDet['branchpost'];
}
```

But a better way to do it would be

```
while($userDet = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result1))
{
    $array[$userDet['id']] = array(
         'forename' => $userDet['forename'],
         'surname'  => $userDet['surname'],
         […]
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following output:

```
 var jsonData = 
    [
        "john,doe,0777777777,some address,some postcode", // first line
        "jane,doe,0777777777,some address,some post",     // second line
        "john,doe,0777777777,some address,some postcode"  // third line
    ]
```

So, later:

```
console.log( jsonData[0] ); // output first line
console.log( jsonData[1] ); // output second line
etc.
```